# Maven to Gradle -- command line options

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm making a case for moving our builds from Maven to Gradle. Below are a few of the Maven command-line options my team finds useful. What are the Gradle equivalent choices?

- -am,--also-makeIf project list is specified, also build projects required by the list
- -amd,--also-make-dependentsIf project list is specified, also build projects that depend on projects on the list
- -o,--offline   Work offline
- -pl,--projects    Build specified reactor projects
  instead of all projects
- -rf,--resume-from Resume reactor from specified project

Maven Examples:

I only want to build the sub-project I'm working on and its dependencies.

```
mvn install --also-makeIf --projects :my-sub-project
```

After fixing an build issue, I want to start the build from the point of failure.

```
mvn install --resume-from :my-sub-project
```

I don't want to download external dependencies from an central repo.

```
mvn install --offline
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some rough analogues:

- `-am`: `buildNeeded` (This triggers a full build of all upstream projects; building those parts of upstream projects that are required to fulfill the command at hand is automatic in Gradle.)
- `-amd`: `buildDependents`
- `-o`: `--offline`
- `-pl`: `:subproject1:build :subproject2:build`
- `-rf`: No direct analogue (not reliable, wouldn't work for parallel builds, etc.), but Gradle's incremental build will get you to the "resume point" quickly.

Note that Gradle's core concepts differ significantly from Maven's. To give one example, in Gradle build order is solely determined by task relationships, and there is no such concept as an execution dependency between projects. Due to these differences, some Maven features aren't necessary or useful in Gradle, some you get for free, and some come in a different form.